# Machine Learning for Financial News

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, nltk

I have a list of news articles from various Financial Websites like Bloomberg, MarketWatch, CNN etc. I want to classify the articles based on their financial relevance so as to know if any financial distress or any crisis is involved or not.

I have developed a program in Python using NLTK which gives a score to each article based on its financial relevance.

Currently, I am using a list/lexicon of Keywords like:

- market
- financial
- loss
- loan , etc.

and checking how many words from this list are present in the news article and keeping a score for each and then adding all the word scores to get an overall score.

Similarly I have list/lexicon of finance phrases:

- fail to agree with creditors
- file for bankruptcy
- file for chapter 11, etc.

Scores from this list and the above list are added and then an overall score is assigned to an article which is an indicator of its relevance.

I want to incorporate machine learning in this process and want to take already classified news articles from this above approach as the training set.

Please help in finding best algorithm to achieve this.

Comment: This question is better to ask here: [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classification machine-learning problem and Logistic Regression would do the trick:

[Logistic Regression Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression)